# sorting Order by hour of the server

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

i have a table CLIENT_HOUR

```
CLIENT_ID(varchar)  THE_TIME(time 7)   HOUR_MIN   HOUR_MAX
850505              09:00:00.0000000   6          9
850505              12:00:00.0000000   10         12
850505              15:00:00.0000000   13         15
850505              18:00:00.0000000   16         18
```

i want to sort depend on the hour on computer.
example: 
the hour of computer is < 9 then listing  hour 9,... 
9>  the hour of computer is < 12 then listing  hour 12,... 
12> the hour of computer is < 15 then listing  hour 15,... 
15> the hour of computer is < 18 then listing  hour 18,....

that meant i want to show the first element that correspond with the hour of computer.

i m using C# 4.0 and SQL server 2008 R2. i don't know if i can do this i SQL or in C#.
i prefer in SQL wise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are building the SQL statement in C#.

There's probably a way to retrieve just the hour from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in SQL but at present I don't have access to MS SQL to try it out.

I write mostly in VB.NET so here's the code I would normally use to build a SQL statement.

```
Dim SQLString As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CLIENT_HOUR WHERE HOUR_MIN >= {0} AND HOUR_MAX <= {1}", Now.AddHours(-3).Hour, Now.Hour)
```

There's an obvious issue with this when the time is between midnight and 3AM.  Also it looks like you want to select based on time blocks of 3 hours.

You could use this

```
        Dim SQLString As String
        Select Case Now.Hour
            Case 0 To 3
                SQLString = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_HOUR WHERE HOUR_MIN >= 0 AND HOUR_MAX <= 3"
            Case 4 To 6
                SQLString = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_HOUR WHERE HOUR_MIN >= 4 AND HOUR_MAX <= 6"
        End Select
```

You could also write a T-SQL and pass the hour from C# as a parameter to the function but you might as well build the SQL in C# and call it directly.

[Convert VB.NET To C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Comment: thanks you, but in your code it not select all of the item. what i want is always show 4 item but, only the first item that change depends on hour of computer. That meant i can not use WHERE, but only ORDER BY

Comment: You might want to look at TOP option for SQL.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp